# Cannot run Rake file

Tags: rake

I am configuring  Jenkins with my Cucumber / Watir /Web Driver Scripts

### I am testing the rake file  per the following command -

### * Rake features

My rake file looks like this …..

require 'cucumber/rake/task'
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
 t.cucumber_opts = '*.feature'
end

*I get the following error

---

:/Ruby193/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber *.feature
The system cannot find the path specified.
←[31mCould not find json-1.7.5 in any of the sources←[0m

---

•   I installed the  json 1.7.5 Gem
•   My rake file path appears to be in order
•   My ruby version is ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
•   I installed the Dev Kit
•   And  I did the install bundler

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the "rake" command from the command line first inside the project folder.Also make this task a default if you are not specfiying to run it particluarly.Like:

task :default => :features